# How can I instantiate Services in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, onion-architecture

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 project using an Onion Architecture where I have repositories and services and I use Services from my controller. In my controller, I need to use the `IGenericService` variables I created, but how can I instantiate these variables? The problem being that my Service needs a `IRepository` for its constructor, and in turn `IRepository`needs to be initialized too.

What I tried was `AddSingleton(IGenericService<MyClass>, GenericService<MyClass>)` in the method `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in the `Startup.cs` file but it doesn't seem to help.

**Edit** As suggested my @Nkosi I am trying to resolve dependencies and followed this tutorial to do so : http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/ . My problem now is that I get an `invalid operation exception`  :

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Repository.PrincipalServerContext' while attempting to activate 'WebExploitv2.Controllers.NavigationController'

My startup.cs looks like this now:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureServices(services);
        var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllerAsServices(typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));

        services.AddSingleton<IGenericRepository<Web_Documents>, GenericRepository<Web_Documents>>();
        services.AddSingleton<IGenericService<Web_Documents>, GenericService<Web_Documents>>();

        services.AddSingleton<IGenericRepository<Web_Categories>, GenericRepository<Web_Categories>>();
        services.AddSingleton<IGenericService<Web_Categories>, GenericService<Web_Categories>>();

        services.AddSingleton<IGenericService<Web_User_joint_Profils>, GenericService<Web_User_joint_Profils>>();
        services.AddSingleton<IGenericRepository<Web_User_joint_Profils>, GenericRepository<Web_User_joint_Profils>>();

        services.AddSingleton<IGenericRepository<Web_Group_joint_Profils>, GenericRepository<Web_Group_joint_Profils>>();
        services.AddSingleton<IGenericService<Web_Group_joint_Profils>, GenericService<Web_Group_joint_Profils>>();


        services.AddSingleton<IMenuService, MenuService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMenuRepository, MenuRepository>();
    }
}
```

I also added a `DefaultDependencyResolver` class :

```
public class DefaultDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public DefaultDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }
}
```

Next I have the `ServiceProviderExtension` class:

```
public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddControllerAsServices(this IServiceCollection services, IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes)
    {
        foreach(var type in controllerTypes)
        {
            services.AddTransient(type);
        }
        return services;
    }
}
```

Finally in my controller, I have Interfaces of `GenericService` which allows me to access `Repository` and in turn access my DB. I use the followed interfaces for instantiation

```
    private IGenericService<Web_User_joint_Profils> _userProfileService;
    private IGenericService<Web_Group_joint_Profils> _groupProfileService;
    private IGenericService<Web_Categories> _categoryService;
    PrincipalServerContext context;
    private NavigationController(PrincipalServerContext context, IGenericService<Web_User_joint_Profils> userProfileService, IGenericService<Web_Group_joint_Profils> groupProfileService, IGenericService<Web_Categories> categoryService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userProfileService = userProfileService;
        _groupProfileService = groupProfileService;
        _categoryService = categoryService;
    }
```

Note that My `GenericService` takes POCOs as generics in order to know where to look in Database. So for each of these in `Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` I added an `AddSingleton` method to register these services and repositories with the DI container.
Any ideas why I get this exception?

Comment: You need to register all dependencies in the object graph

Comment: Documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: Is it normal that I can't use `AddDbContext<MyContext>()` method? Many  others work fine, but I can't for this one, or even `AddMvc()`

Comment: Can you confirm what version of MVC you are using? You may be mixing versions.

Comment: Version=5.2.3.0 : and it's not Core

Comment: smh. Ok you should have stated that first. `IServiceCollection` is part of Asp.Net Core. And you are using MVC 5.*. The good news that the DI package is modularized and can be used via nuget. It would how ever require you to make custom changes to accommodate using it.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Erm ok, will look for this. I can still use the IServiceCollection though, and use methods like AddTransient, or AddScope etc ... So that's a bit weird, more digging i guess.

Comment: I'm checking I know I came across an article with this just the other day

Comment: Got it. follow this. http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/ while it says MVC4 it will also work with MVC5

Comment: Thanks a bunch man! I don't know why there were asp.net core tags, I don't remember putting them here, weird. I'm reading and trying the tutorial ...

Comment: I'm thinking this will not work properly, I keep getting errors, it seems that packages like Ninject or AutoFac are more adapted to what I want to do, would you agree? Because I found only tutorials for Core in the way you explained, and I have many methods missing / execution errors.

Comment: I would say yes to using the other containers even though they should also be able to integrate with core DI. I still believe the issue is with how you are setting up or registering the dependencies/object graphs but can't be certain given the limited about of details in the question.

Comment: Probably, I get error `unable to resolve service for type "MyContext" while attempting to activate "ControllerName". If I can make it work this way, it would be better

Comment: Ok here is the thing. update your question as a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. It will save all the back and forth as it will give those trying to help you a better picture of what is actually going on.

Comment: Add the singletons. Need to see if you are leaving anything out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148481/discussion-between-nkosi-and-leonard-laiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather simple, using `IServiceCollection` instance that is being passed to `ConfigureServices` method by the run time you do:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAbstraction, ConcreteImplementation>();
```

or, for a transient lifetime scope:

```
services.AddTransient<IAbstraction, ConcreteImplementation>();
```

or, in your case:

```
services.AddSingleton<IGenericService<MyClass>, GenericService<MyClass>>();
```

Comment: This does not work I don't know why, it's the solution I'd come upon but I keep getting Null Reference Exception

Comment: @LéonardLaiter how a you trying to inject the dependencies?

Comment: I believe this is the step I skipped :p Reading the doc that @Nkosi posted and I will tell you when I get there.

Comment: @LéonardLaiter you should do constructor injection or to resolve your services through an instance of IServiceProvider.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call services inside a startup.

Instance your `IGenericService` as a private readonly, then create the constructor to call in `startup.cs` or where ever you decide to use it.

```
private readonly IGenericService _genericService = new GenericService();
public IGenericService GenericService
{
    get{ return _genericService; }
    set{ _genericService = value; }
}
```

Now you call your classes like:

```
GenericService.Method();
```